# Incrementar 1 a cada elemento de una lista y guardarla en la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql

El problema es el siguiente: tengo una tabla en la base de datos con un campo posición el cual recibe valores enteros, después cargo una lista con los datos de mi tabla,  ahora necesito que al momento de insertar un nuevo registro en la posicion 1 y si la posicion 1 ya existe en la base de datos la recorra al numero 2 y si existe el 2 lo recorra al 3 y asi sucesivamente. Todo esto con java.

```
public String accionRecorre() throws Exception {
 lstSecciones=adminConfiguracionAsociadosDao.getLstMostrarSecciones();
 int indice=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tfIndex"));
   for(int i=0; i<lstSecciones.size(); i++){
    posInicial=lstSecciones.get(i).getIndex();
        if(indice==posInicial){
           posInicial++; //es en esta parte donde no sé cómo condicionar      
            }

 adminConfiguracionAsociadosDao.insertarSeccion(idAsociado,nombre, visible,    posInicial, estado); 

 return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Sería factible recuperar esa lista de BD ya ordenada por ese campo posición? Y segunda pregunta, ¿con qué versión de Java estás trabajando? (asumiré que Java 8, pero si es una versión anterior, sólo será cuestión de que ajustes el código)

Si no puedes recuperarla ordenada, la ordenas antes tú mismo con

```
lstTmp = lstSecciones.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(<TuClase>::getIndex)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Una vez tengas la lista ordenada, ya puedes pasar a procesarla:

```
int i = 1;
for(<TuClase> elem: lstTmp) {
    if (elem.getIndex() == i) {
        elem.setIndex(++i);
        //Cualquier otra acción que debas hacer
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Ya que estás puedes procesarla en la cadena de métodos: `sorted(//Comparator...).map(i -> i.setIndex(i.getIndex() + i))`. Puede acortarse si hay un método específico para aumentar el `index`.

Comment: Lo he pensado, pero leyendo la pregunta, me ha entrado la duda de que, tal vez, no siempre estén todos los índices, es decir, que pueda eliminarse alguno y la secuencia fuese 1, 2, 3, 6.

Answer (score 0):

Descargo:
Esto debería ir como un comentario, pero como no tengo aún el nivel de reputación entonces lo coloco aquí como una solución al mismo problema que en una ocasión tuve que resolver.

Teniendo una tabla `TABLA_A` y conociendo la cantidad máxima posible de registros que puede contener en cualquier momento, puedes hacer un `JOIN` con otra `TABLA_B` que contenga los valores posibles y te retorne sólo aquellos que estén en la `TABLA_B` y no en la `TABLA_A`, con lo que te serviría para localizar el primer "*hueco*" entre filas.

En el código siguiente, mi base de datos es oracle, utilizo la tabla `DUAL` para generar los valores del 1 al `:LIMITE`, donde le establezco un valor X que supera a la máxima de registros que considero que la tabla `TU_TABLA` contiene actualmente. La ventaja de esto es que la propia base de datos es quien se encarga de localizar el hueco y no el programa que deberá recorrer fila por fila hasta localizar dónde insertar el nuevo valor.

```sql
SELECT A.ID AS OCUPADO, B.POSICION AS HUECO_DISPONIBLE
FROM TU_TABLA A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT LEVEL AS POSICION
    FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :LIMITE
) B ON A.ID = B.POSICION
WHERE A.ID IS NULL
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Con el `ROWNUM` lo que hago es que me retorne unicamente la primera fila del conjunto de valores disponibles.